# Weird behaviour of Solr text search in Hybris

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

In my project,a strange problem is occuring.We have configured the Solr to use four attributes(namely code,summary, name and keywords of product) for text search.When we search for something,the products not having exact match also appear and that too in higher ranking.How to find out the issue and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Give a proper example of the query, the result and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

How to find out the issue?

The common way to identify what is happening while indexing and query time is to go to analysis (select core->Analysis)

`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/{{collection_name}}/analysis`

select field on which query is perform and put the text you are searching and just hit analyse. This will show what tokenizer and filters are getting applied on field. For partial match it could be`solr.NGramTokenizerFactory`.